# Can't see messages in Skype

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

I am experiencing a peculiar issue where I can't see new messages that got sent to me nor messages that I sent to someone else.  I am running `Windows 8.1` and `Skype 7.1.0.15`.

I can see some old messages, when I scroll down and send (or receive) new message scrollbar jumps up.  I have tried restarting Skype without luck.

Comment: I assume your using the desktop client based on the version.  Can you confirm if the `Windows Store` version of Skype has the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Quit Skype and delete `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Skype` then start Skype and you should be solid.